# Openstack Single Physical Network

Tags: networking, xen, openstack

I am trying to deploy openstack grizzly on a 12 node cluster. I want to use the xen hypervisor. I currently have xenserver installed, and I have 3 virtual machines running Ubuntu 12.04 to use for the control, compute, and network nodes.

Is it at all possible to combine the VM and Management Network into one physical network? I only have one router, so I need to use only one network. I got my setup pretty much working using this [guide](http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/basic-install/apt/content/basic-install_intro.html). But now, I only have access to a single physical network.

Is there a way to have VM and Management traffic on the same network? Security is not a concern at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: You only have one router?  Your router doesn't support vlans?  Running a compute node inside a virtual machine is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yes. I should have been more clear. All physical machines are plugged into an  unmanaged switch, which is plugged into a router. The switch does not support vlans. As far as I can tell, running every node in a xen vm is the only way to use xen as the hypervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a single physical network, and the best way to do so is to use VLANs to create multiple logical networks on top of your sole physical network. But since you say your switch lacks VLAN support, I recommend you investigate GRE instead. I'm guessing your switch doesn't support VXLAN either, but if it did, that would probably outperform GRE.